# How to change ctrl key to AltGR key by editing registry?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, autohotkey

I'm changing the <kbd>Caps</kbd> key to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> by using this registry key:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]             
"ScancodeMap"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,1d,00,3a,00,00,00,00,00
```

And I want to use the original <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  key as another modifier for `AutoHotkey`.
So I thought <kbd>Alt GR</kbd> is a good choice to use as a modifier.

But I couldn't figure out how to remap the original <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  key to <kbd>Alt GR</kbd>.
Does anyone know how to change it via registry?

If there is better solution, I will go for it.

I'm using windows 10.

Comment: ::Ctrl;       Send {alt}{GR}; Is that the result you're looking for?

Comment: @ejbytes The way I read it, he is looking to change his `Ctrl` key to an `AltGr` key in way that AHK doesn't recognize his `Caps Lock` key as a `Ctrl` key, because he edited the registry to rebind it that way.

Comment: @ejbytes Sorry, I couldn't figure out how the code works.

Comment: @TheKB I want let AHK recognize `Caps Lock` as a `Ctrl` and original `Ctrl` as a `AltGr`. I'm not sure I'm understanding correctly what you wrote.

Comment: @ironsand Yes, that's what I wrote.

Comment: @ironsand Has my method worked?

Answer (score 2):

## Method 1: Use SharpKeys

---

You could use [SharpKeys](https://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/) to remap your keys. This changes the registry for you and allows you to easily manage key mappings.

1. Click `Add` on the main screen
2. Under `Map this key` click `Type Key` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
3. Under `To this key` find and click `AltGr`
4. Click `Ok`
5. Click `Write to Registry` and then logout

*Note: You may have to do steps 1-4 again for <kbd>Caps</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>*
**Edit**: It appears that the key <kbd>AltGr</kbd> is not supported by SharpKeys. However, this answer is still valid for other keys so I will leave it for informational purposes. The registry method of rebinding, outlined below, works for this key remap.
[Source](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/)

### Method 2: Use the Registry

---

If you want to do it via the registry you can do:

> 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 aa aa bb bb aa aa bb bb 00 00 00 00

It's a bit complicated but I will try to explain. For remap 1, `aaaa` is the scancode of the key you want to map **to**. `bbbb` is the scancode of the key you want to map **from**. Same thing for remap 2. This is what you would put into the registry key `ScancodeMap` and what `SharpKeys` does for you.

A table showing the values and meaning of the DWORDS:

```
        Value:     Interpretation:                                          Entered as: 
DWORD 1 0x00000000 Header: Version. Set all to zeroes                       00 00 00 00 
DWORD 2 0x00000000 Header: Flags. Set all to zeroes                         00 00 00 00 
DWORD 3 0x00000002 Number of entries in the map, including null terminator  02 00 00 00 
DWORD 4 0x003A0000 Remove CAPS LOCK (0x3A --> 0x00)                         00 00 3A 00 
DWORD 5 0x00000000 Null Terminator                                          00 00 00 00
```

*In the above table, the mapping of <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> is an example.* Also, thanks to @Guitar Shoe Dave for the suggestion.
[Source](http://www.mech.utah.edu/~bamberg/resources/CapsLock/CapsLock.html)

---

In your case the value would be:

> 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 1d 00 3a 00 1d 02 1d 00 00 00 00 00

*Note: You'll have to logoff and back in again to see the resulting changes.*

Comment: I installed `SharpKeys`, but I couldn't find `AltGr` key in `to this key` list. What is the exact name of the key?

Comment: @ironsand It appears that it is not there. But I believe `1d02` is the scancode for AltGr (I used the on-screen keyboard to test this) So the registry entry would be `00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 1d 00 3a 00 1d 02 1d 00 00 00 00 00`. Could you try this and see if you get the correct results?

Comment: Please consider adding protocol documentation related to scancodes. Here's one which breaks it down a bit. 

http://www.mech.utah.edu/~bamberg/resources/CapsLock/CapsLock.html  
Also, here's a good reference of scancodes to include the long lived power management buttons (these ones are fun to play with)
https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes.html  . I love your reply.